SharePoint Tracking List Glitch - Last Row gets deleted when a column is added or hidden
I set up a team SharePoint site using the Project Management template. It includes two separate tracking lists. An annoying glitch in both lists is that if I add or hide a column, it will delete the last row in the list.
Anyone else experience this? Is there a way to fix it? I don't want to have to worry about me or someone else on my team accidently delete rows without realizing it, or have to always put a dummy row at the end of each list to catch the glitch.
Ideas?
